# cronjob in docker container?

Tags: docker, cron

i am trying to run a cronjob in a docker container.

to do that, i added a line to my Dockerfile like this:

```
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "0 0 * * * cd /usr/src/app/scripts/testApiReturns && /usr/src/app/scripts/testApiReturns/testApi.sh") | crontab -
```

when running the container, i can go to its shell and check if the job is in the root crontab, and it is.

but still it does not run in the runtime of the docker. running the script directly it works.

how can i figure out why it does not run periodically?

thanks for ideas!!

Comment: `RUN` is executed when building container, not when Docker images starts.

Comment: but is this not what i need (?) : i build a docker container and while building i add the cronjob so that  it runs in runtime?

Comment: Docker build process is run in multiple layers, you only start cronjob in one of these disposable layers. After build it stops any scripts execution. Means you start cronjob in image ABC, but final result is in image XYZ